# Azure Logic App trigger a REST API in Azure API Manegement

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, azure-logic-app-standard

I have an Azure Logic App and Azure API Management. I need to call the APIs from the Logic APP.
But when I try to add the action "Call an Azure API Management API" I get this error: "GetCallFailed. The API 'apiManagementOperation' could not be found."

Any pieces of advice on this error?
It's a Logic App (Standard).

[image]

Comment: Do you have required permissions on the APIM Service instance? Alternatively, you can try the HTTP request connector to call API.

Comment: @PankajMore, APIM is in the same Resource Group. I have access to it, can change it, etc. Or do I need some specific permissions? Or do I have to configure Access control with identity?

Yeah, thanks, I know about HTTP connectors and it works for me now. But it's better to move to the API Management connector directly, because using the HTTP connector I have to specify access code as a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs.es-es/blob/a189b046e33af916278f9cde0df619262f69ec1c/articles/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare.md#capacidades-modificadas-limitadas-no-disponibles-o-no-admitidas), Functionalities in Standard Logic app are either limited, unavailable, or are not supported.

> Some built-in triggers and actions are not available, such as Slider Window, Batch, Azure App Service, and Azure API Management.

While connecting to your API Management directly, this feature is available in the Consumption logic app - `Azure API Management`.

[image]

Currently, the only option available in the Standard Logic App is to use an `HTTP` Connector.

[image]